# Does every CAT(0) space embed in a measurable integral of $\mathbb{R}$-trees?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, alexandrov-geometry, metric-embeddings, non-positive-curvature

**Question 1.** Does every CAT(0) space embed isometrically inside an integral of $\mathbb{R}$-trees?

Here an *integral* of $\mathbb{R}$ trees means the set of functions from a measure space $\mathcal{F}$ to a measurable field of based $\mathbb{R}$-trees over $\mathcal{F}$, so that the squared distance from the basepoint is integrable, as described in Proposition 44 and Remark 45 of https://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0894-0347-06-00525-X .

(Originally the question referred to $\ell^2$ products of $\mathbb{R}$-trees, but Nicolas Monod below gave an argument that these do not suffice, and suggested the generalization.)

Really I'm most interested in the finite version of this question (where we also don't need to talk about $\mathbb{R}$-trees):

**Question 2.** Does every $k$-element subset of a CAT(0) space embed isometrically in a (finite) product of metric trees?

To go from Question 2 to Question 1, one would presumably attempt a limiting approximation argument, although it's a little complicated, since an approximation for $k$ points doesn't necessarily have an obvious relation to the approximation for $k+1$ points.

If you consider the set of possible squared-distances between $k$ points in any CAT(0) space, you get a subset $MC0_k$ of $\mathbb{R}^{\binom{k}{2}}$. This is clearly closed under scaling, and the fact that a product of CAT(0) spaces is still CAT(0) implies that $MC0_k$ is a convex subset. On the other hand, you could look at $MT_k$, the set of possible squared-distances between $k$ points in a tre. Question 2 is then asking whether the convex hull of $MT_k$ is $MC0_k$. This reformulation makes it clear that, if the answer to Question 2 is affirmative, you would need at most $\binom{k}{2}$ different trees to realize any $k$-element subset of a CAT(0) space.

For $k=4$, the answer to Question 2 appears to be affirmative. Petrunin gives an elegant characterization of which squared-distances between 4 points can be realized in a CAT(0) space: https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.5329
Let me sketch the argument.

If the four distances are realized in $\mathbb{E}^3$, we are done. Otherwise, the four distances can (generically) be realized by a space $X_0$ obtained by gluing together three triangles around a vertex, so that the angle sum around the vertex is greater than $2\pi$. Then consider the space $X_1$ obtained by deleting one of these triangles. This is again CAT(0), and all distances are the same except between one pair of points. The distances in $X_0$ can be realized as a convex combination of he distances in $X_1$ and the distances in another space $X_3$ where that changed length is shortened until the three triangles embed in $\mathbb{E}^2$.

You can proceed in a similar way, deleting the triangles one at a time, until you reduce $X_0$ to a convex combination of a tripod and spaces that embed in $\mathcal{E}^2$.

It looks like one could also push this through for $k=5$, although there are many more cases to consider.

*(Moved the question about extreme points here: [What are the extremal CAT(0) metrics?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/204724/what-are-the-extreme-points-in-the-space-of-cat0-metrics) )*

This is a version of this old question:
[Length inequalities in trees and CAT(0) spaces](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/163706/length-inequalities-in-trees-and-cat0-spaces)
However, I started off asking the earlier question in a slightly confusing dual form, so I wanted to restate it with a more easily-understood question first.

*(Edited to refer to $\mathbb{R}$-trees)*

---

Nicolas Monod gave an elegant argument against Question 1 using products. I accepted his answer, but edited the question to refer to integrals instead, which is the natural generalization.

(Or, if you prefer finitary questions, Question 2 is still open, and Nicolas' argument against embedding in a product of trees doesn't really give any evidence against it.)

Comment: Maybe split this question into at least two separate questions?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I split off the question about extreme points.

Comment: You might be interested in a result of Buyalo and Schroeder, who showed any hyperbolic group *quasi-isometrically* embeds into a product of trees: http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0509355 .

Comment: @HJRW: Thanks, although it's not exactly what I'm asking.

Comment: @DylanThurston, that's why I posted a comment, and not an answer!

Comment: What's the ettiquette on when I should create a new question? Should I go ahead and make one for the variation about taking measurable integrals of trees?

Comment: @DylanThurston: since the question is still in activity I would suggest to either edit it now to include the measurable integrals, or wait a little (until there's no longer activity here) before starting a new separate question (which should link to this one).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is not possible; sorry for just posting a sketch but I am not on MO :-(

For instance a generic geodesic triangle in the hyperbolic plane does not embed in a finite product of trees.

Suppose you have a finite product $X$ of uniquely geodesic metric spaces $X_n$  with the "pythagorean" distance on the product. Then it is uniquely geodesic and any geodesic segment $\sigma\colon[a,b]\to X$ is of the form $\sigma(t)=(\sigma_n(a_n t))_n$ where $a_n\geq 0$ is a sequence with $\sum a_n^2 = 1$ and each $\sigma_n$ is a geodesic in $X_n$. This characterisation is not entirely trivial, but very well-known (see e.g. Bridson--Haefliger).

Now in the case at hand you would deduce that the distance between two geodesics issuing from a common point would be a piecewise affine function, which it definitely isn't for hyperbolic geometry.

The fact about geodesics extends to infinite sums, and even to integrals (see e.g. Proposition 44 in https://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0894-0347-06-00525-X )

The latter part of the argument above (piecewise affine) does not extend as is to this "integral" setting though.

Comment: I don't think you use "generic" anywhere, the argument works for any subset of $\mathbb{H}^2$ containing a pair of non-collinear segments. Also the argument shows that the distance $f(t)=d(u_t,v_t)$ between two speed-one geodesics $(u_t),(v_t)$  will be of the form $f(t)=\sqrt{\sum_i h_i(t)^2}$ with $h_i$ piecewise affine, which is not necessarily piecewise affine but is enough for the argument.

Comment: @Yves: (1) yes that's what I meant by generic (I'd have said scalene but then I'd have gotten picked on as it's too strong) and (2) yes you're right I guess "non-analytic" would be the lazy overkill!

Comment: Thanks for the nice argument! But you're addressing a question I didn't ask. In Question 1, I'm asking about embedding in an infinite product. In Question 2, I'm asking about finite products, but only about embedding finitely many points in a distance-preserving way, not their convex hull. The three corners of the triangle can trivially be embedded in a product of trees, and your argument doesn't rule out embedding a finite subset of the triangle (although it might well be impossible). As you note, it also doesn't rule out embedding inside infinite constructions.

Comment: Also, welcome to MO!

Comment: (I usually understand "generic" in the sense almost all configurations, where "almost all" means something such as: all but finitely/countably many, all except measure zero, all but meager, etc.)

Comment: @DylanThurston: I understand the argument to work for infinite products. In this case the distance function has the form $u(t)=\sqrt{\sum_i{h_i(a_it)}}$, where $h_i$ is a (convex nonnegative) piecewise affine function with slopes in $\{-2,0,2\}$, $a_i\ge 0$ and $\sum a_i^2=1$, and some additional summability condition ensuring that $u<\infty$. Then a little argument is needed to ensure that $u$ cannot be analytic unless it's affine.

Comment: @Yves: ...or all but in a subvariety of positive codimension? like here :P

Comment: Other argument: In an arbitrary product of trees, I would guess that the convex hull of three points is 2-dimensional. However, in complex hyperbolic space, the convex hull of a generic (hum, hum) triple of points is 4 dimensional. Here generic means not contained in a totally real subspace.

Comment: I see. The point is that in $f(t) = \sqrt{\sum_i h_i(a_i t)^2}$, if one of the $h_i$ is only piecewise affine, you get a positive delta-mass in $f''(t)$ that you can't cancel. So that indeed answers Question 1, although it also suggests that the "integral" setting that @NicolasMonod suggested is more natural.

Comment: @NicolasMonod , it's not true that the convex hull of three points in a product of trees is 2-dimensional. I worked out an explicit example with three points in a product of three trees.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an answer to the 1st question using group theory. Any NPC symmetric space whose isometrically group has property T does not embed isometrically into a product of real trees. The reason is that if you have a group acting isometrically on an unbounded subset of a product of trees, projection of the subset to at least one factor is unbounded, hence you can use this factor to construct a space with measurable walls on which the group acts. But such action cannot exist for a group with property T.

However, if you asked me about a product of rank 2 irreducible affine buildings, I would not know how to rule this out.

Comment: What's a "space with measurable walls", and how do you get such an action from a projection onto an unbounded tree?

Comment: Also, for completeness, I suppose it's easy to construct a NPC symmetric space whose isometry group has property T? If I understand the wikipedia entry correctly, lattices in a quaternionic hyperbolic space should do the job here.

Comment: I don't understand Misha's argument and how you get an action fro a bare isometric embedding. Here's a replacement. Any subset of a ($\ell^2$) product of real trees has an isometric embedding into a Hilbert space endowed with the square root of its distance. While any group of isometries of a subset of a Hilbert space extends to a group of isometries of the whole Hilbert space. Hence if $X$ is a proper metric space embedding isometrically into a l2 product of real trees then $\mathrm{Isom}(X)$ has the Haagerup Property (hence is not T unless compact).

Comment: @YCor, to be sure I understand you, when you assert that 'any group of isometries of a subset of a Hilbert space extends to a group of isometries of the whole Hilbert space', you also want that a fixed-point free action extends to a fixed-point free action?

Comment: I didn't say this. But by definition the action of $Isom(X)$ on $X$ is proper, and hence the action of $Isom(X)$ on the Hilbert space containing isometrically $X$ will be metrically proper (in particular if the orbits of $Isom(X)$ in $X$ are unbounded, then there will be no fixed point, but it's not the best formulation, properness is more natural here and yields stronger consequences).

Comment: PS: the problem is not to "find a good" extension of the action, because if we have an isometric action on a subset a Hilbert space, the isometric extension to its closed affine hull is unique. All we have to care is how this extension behaves given information about the original action. And for isometric actions (on arbitrary metric spaces!), metric properness is nice because it can be read on any nonempty invariant subspace.

Comment: @YCor, can you post your proposed answer separately, so that we can discuss it properly rather than in a comment section?

Comment: Having read up on spaces with measured walls, I'm now confused how you are getting an action on a space with measured walls from the map to a tree. The map to a tree gives a set of walls, but it won't be group-invariant, and to make it group-invariant you might kill the finiteness properties.

Spaces with measured walls were apparently introduced here:
Cherix, Martin, and Valette, _Spaces with measured walls, the Haagerup property and property (T)_, Ergod. Thy. & Dynam. Sys., **24** (2004), 1895--1908.

Comment: @YCor, your argument would apply in much greater generality, since, I believe, for any metric space, if you take the square root of the distances you get a space that embeds in Hilbert space. (This amounts to saying that the PSD cone contains a polyhedral cone.) But then your conclusion seems to be too strong, if I'm understanding right.

Comment: No it's certainly not true that for any metric space $(X,d)$, the metric space $(X,\sqrt{d})$ embeds isometrically into a Hilbert space. A counterexample is the graph on 5 vertices that is complete-bipartite 2+3.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23464/discussion-between-dylan-thurston-and-ycor).

Comment: Oops, my argument only shows that in an $\ell^1$-product of trees, the square root of the distance is Hilbertian. Right now I'm not sure whether it holds for the $\ell^2$-product. It would work if it were true that the $\ell^2$-product of 2 $\ell^1$-spaces is always $\ell^1$-embeddable.

Answer (score 3):

It meant to be an answer to another question, https://mathoverflow.net/a/406833/, but it is an answer to this question as well.